# I cannot fully uninstall numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I wrote "pip uninstall numpy", and it appears uninstalled. For example when I put import pandas, it returns

```
module 'numpy' has no attribute '__version__'
```

But when I run "import numpy" it lets me import it. However, it does when i ask it

```
print numpy.__file__
```

it returns

```
module 'numpy' has no attribute '__file__'
```

I'm using Google Cloud Console, and can't seem to install packages because of this numpy issue.

One of the errors I receive is

"Something is wrong with the numpy installation. While importing we detected an older version of numpy in ['/home/davidxmkong/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy']. One method of fixing this is to repeatedly uninstall numpy until none is found, then reinstall this version."

Comment: Have you tried doing what is suggested on the error message?

Comment: You could also delete anaconda3 and reinstall it. I'm guessing it already comes with everything you need since that's what they claim it to be.

Comment: @Andreas perhaps I don't understand what they mean when they say "repeatedly uninstall numpy". I've done  "pip uninstall numpy" many times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I installed the 2018-12 version of Anaconda, and it appears like the problem has been solved.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with accepting your own answer after a short wait.